# Splash screen before appbootstrapper.configure

Tags: c#, wpf, autofac, splash-screen, caliburn.micro

So I have searched around for this but I couldn't find anything that matched what I needed. I have a WPF application and I am using Caliburn Micro and Autofac.

My App.xaml is

```
<Application x:Class="Drogo.Meera.Ui.Wpf.Launcher.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:launcher="clr-namespace:Drogo.Meera.Ui.Wpf.Launcher">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <launcher:AppBootstrapper x:Key="AppBootstrapper"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And the AppBootstrapper is

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    private IContainer _container;

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        this._log.Debug("AppBootstrapper ctor...");
        this.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this._log.Debug("AppBootstrapper.OnStartup");
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this._log.Debug("ENTER:AppBootstrapper.Configure");
        try
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.Register<IWindowManager>(c => new WindowManager()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.Register<IEventAggregator>(c => new EventAggregator()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            // register all other dependencies on the builder

            this._container = builder.Build();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._log.Error(ex.ToString());
        }

        this._log.Debug("EXIT:AppBootstrapper.Configure");
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
    ...
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
    ...
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        this._container.InjectProperties(instance);
    }
}
```

Ok, so my application runs up fine (I haven't defined a main window yet, that's still work in progress). I am anticipating that I will have a number of Autofac modules from referenced assemblies where I will be loading all dependencies during the `Configure` method above and I expect that this could take a few seconds (possibly 4-5 seconds or longer).

What I would like is to load a splash screen as soon as the application starts (I am interested in a singleton SplashScreen that can be updated with progress) and before (preferably) the `AppBootstrapper` executes.

I have seen the examples of using an image with build type set to SplashScreen but that's is not what I want. I want a Window based splash screen with a TextBlock that can be updated by each of the Autofac Modules with progress while the application is starting up. I have also tried creating a splash screen in the `OnStartup` method but that is too late as this happens after `Configure`.

I am fairly new to WPF and even newer to Caliburn Micro but have a very good understanding of Autofac and would be great if anyone can suggest the best way to achieve this.

Comment: try this http://blog.m.jedynak.pl/2011/02/dynamic-splash-screen-in-wpf.html

Comment: Thanks @Alex that helped me to come up with a solution that works